# How to set post expiration date and time and move the page to archive after expiration

Tags: posts, categories, date, exclude

My requirement is to move the certain posts from home page category after specified date and time.

I have two category News and Events. Both have so many posts and i dont want to show all the posts on home page. So how can i set the date and time to move the post from home page to archives.